# validate E-mail with white space with regular expression with angular form-builders

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-formbuilder

I am using the form builders to validate the E-mail,

TS:

```
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      userName: [
        '',
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.email,
          Validators.pattern(
            '^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$'
          ),
        ],
      ],
    });
  }

get f() {
    return this.registerForm.controls;
  }

validateEmail() {
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
      console.log('Invalid');
      return;
    }
    console.log(this.registerForm.value.userName + ' is a valid Email');
  }
```

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="validateEmail()">
  <input
    [ngClass]="{
      'is-invalid': submitted && f.userName.errors,
      blueLine: submitted && f.userName.errors
    }"
    type="text"
    formControlName="userName"
  />
  <button (click)="validateEmail()">Validate</button>
</form>
```

There is a requirement that user may enter few white spaces at the end of the E-mail id , how to trim the white spaces at the end of the E-mail before validating the E-mail.

eg:

> "someone.someone.com    " // used 3 white spaces after .com
> this should trim all the white spaces after .com

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rnrqmu?file=src/app/app.component.ts) : you can check the code implementation here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to remove the Validators.email in your validators to allow white spaces in your form control. Next, you need to create a custom validator that will trim the end of the control value first before checking the regex pattern. Then, add the custom validator as one of your validators.

I modified the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2mdf4a?file=src/app/app.component.ts) you created and added my solution.

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  VERSION
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  email: string;
  registerForm: FormGroup;
  submitted: boolean;

  //Constructor
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  // On init function
  ngOnInit() {
    this.submitted = false;
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      userName: ['', [Validators.required, emailWithWhitespaceValidator]],
    });
  }
  get f() {
    return this.registerForm.controls;
  }

  validateEmail() {
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
      console.log('Invalid');
      return;
    }
    console.log(this.registerForm.value.userName + ' is a valid Email');
  }
}

export function emailWithWhitespaceValidator(control: FormControl) {
  const isValid = control.value
    .trimEnd()
    .match('^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$');
  return isValid ? null : {
    isValid: false
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use trimEnd() method:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimEnd

Comment: As soon as i click the button it checks for the regular expression , where the form value will be invalid hence it prints "Invalid" in the console. i want to know how to override the pattern check and trim the white space instead. @EspressoCode